# Black Screen Boot After Installing PPA Radeon Driver

Tags: ati, kubuntu, gpu-driver

I'm on my cell phone now. I just followed the instructions for installing the latest driver via the edgers PPA repo. I'm running Kubuntu 15.10 with full luks encryption. The first time I rebooted I got to the login screen to enter my luks password but the keyboard wasn't responding (That happens every once in a while) so as usual I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and now every time I try to boot I never get to the luks screen. It's just a black screen.

The only thing I can do is keep rebooting and of course access grub. I could really use some guidance here. A lot of solutions for older versions of Ubuntu suggest commands that I can't execute because I can't get to a shell. I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at the black screen.

I'm good at troubleshooting Linux servers but when it comes to a gpu issue on a desktop version I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I just got to the recovery menu using grub. It allowed me to unlock luks. How can I revert back to my previous driver and remove this one?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by booting into recovery and removing every single package using purge that the Ubuntu AMD binary instructions had me install in the first place. I believe it was some kernel module blacklisting that was causing the black screen. I was able to boot into previous kernel installs before removing all I had done. Now I have the latest kernel back. I plan to investigate further into what was preventing me from using the latest driver but for now I'm just happy to have my system back to normal. I of course removed the edgers repo as well though I'll be experimenting with it in the future now that I know how to recover from it.